# Program with flask-socketio and multiprocessing thorws 'LoopExit: This operation would block forever'

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, flask-socketio

first: I am an absolute beginner in python, I used to write PHP before, so if I am getting something complitly wrong please let me know.

I am writing an app. It should serve its information via websockets. I choosed flask-socketio for this. In the background I want to process the data. Because I would like to have the app small I decided against a solution like Celery.

I have shortened the code to:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, url_for, request, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import time
import os

def background_stuff(args):
    while True:
        try:
            print args
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            return e

thread = None
_pool = None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_timers():
    return 'timer'

if __name__=='__main__':
    _pool = Pool(1)
    if os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') == 'true':
        workers = _pool.apply_async(
            func=background_stuff,
            args=('do background stuff',),
        )
    socketio.run(app)
    # app.run()
```

When starting this, i get the following messages:

```
python test/multitest.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with stat
do background stuff
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 336, in _handle_tasks
    for taskseq, set_length in iter(taskqueue.get, None):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
    self.not_empty.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
  File "gevent/_semaphore.pyx", line 112, in gevent._semaphore.Semaphore.acquire (gevent/gevent._semaphore.c:3386)
  File "/home/phil/work/ttimer/server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 338, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
LoopExit: This operation would block forever

do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
127.0.0.1 - - [2015-09-30 00:06:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 120 0.001860
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
^CProcess PoolWorker-1:
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 113, in worker
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
  File "test/multitest.py", line 14, in background_stuff
KeyboardInterrupt
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
    return recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So the background process is working and it answers http requests (127.0.0.1 - - [2015-09-30 00:06:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 120 0.001860). But just ignoring an error because it seems to work does not seem to be a solution for me. Does anyone can tell my what I am doing wrong here?

If you say I can't do it that way can you tell me why? I would like to learn and understand what I am doing wrong.

I read something about monkepatching, but everything suggested threw just more or other errors. I think it is better to work on the first error instead of blindly trying fixes.

```
python -V
Python 2.7.9
```

Greetings

**update**

I added the 2 lines for monkeypatching, this is what I got:

```
$python multitest2.py 
 ^CProcess PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 380, in _handle_results
    task = get()
KeyboardInterrupt

 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with stat
^CProcess PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 380, in _handle_results
    task = get()
KeyboardInterrupt

    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
do background stuff
FAILED to start flash policy server: [Errno 98] Address already in use: ('127.0.0.1', 10843)
$do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
```

On start there is no output at all. After hittinc ctrl-c several times, i get the background stuff output. This continues until i kill the python process via SIGKILL

**update 2**

what I expect to see is

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with stat
do background stuff
do background stuff
do background stuff
```

right after the running of the script. But before I press ctrl-c nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to be aware that the version of Flask-SocketIO that you are using requires gevent, which is a coroutine framework. Using the asynchronous coroutines of gevent with a multiprocessing pool is a strange combination. You are using gevent, so what would make the most sense is to use the gevent [pool](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html) functionality so that everything is consistent.

Now regarding the problem, I think it is likely due to not having the standard library monkey patched at an early stage. I recommend that you add the following lines at the very top of your script (above your imports, make them lines 1 and 2):

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

These will ensure that any calls into standard library for things such as threads, semaphores, etc. go to the gevent implementations.

**Update**: I tried your example. The original version, without monkey-patching, works fine for me, I do not see the LoopExit error that you reported. Adding the monkey patching prevents the background processes from running, as you reported.

In any case, I converted your script to use gevent.pool and that works reliably for me. Here is the edited script:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, url_for, request, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit
from gevent.pool import Pool
import time
import os

def background_stuff(args):
    while True:
        try:
            print args
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            return e

thread = None
_pool = None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_timers():
    return 'timer'

if __name__=='__main__':
    _pool = Pool(1)
    workers = _pool.apply_async(
        func=background_stuff,
        args=('do background stuff',),
    )
    socketio.run(app)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: > Using the asynchronous coroutines of gevent with a multiprocessing pool is a strange combination. 
I think this is the most important thing I need to know. I read about the monkey patching and by inserting these two lines I get other strange errors. I would like to learn the 'correct' way, so i will read about gevent and have a try. Thank you for that link!

Comment: @FrankNord Not sure there are right or wrong ways. My assertion that it is a "strange" combination is because you are using two completely different ways to achieve multitasking. I would not say it is wrong, though. Maybe we should look at those errors that you get when you monkey patch, feel free to add that to another question.

Comment: I know there is not the one way, the quotation marks shoult show that. But after your explanation it seems not the best way for beginners like me to mix those two. Maybe there is a case which needs this solution, but knowledge about booth is needed I think. As you suggested I tried adding those two lines and added the outcome to my initial question. If you like you can think about it and tell me whats happening, I am willing to learn. But for my little project I will stick to a simpler solution, I want to be able to progress with it.

Comment: @FrankNord the stack traces that you added are a result of you pressing Ctrl-C I think. I don't see any other output, what do you expect to see?

Comment: I added my expectations to my question

Comment: I am sorry, I read the tutorial to laearn about gevent and fount a solution I posted below. I totally didn't saw you updated your answer, so my answer sounds not verry thankful. But thank you verry much! You helped me a lot and I now know something about gevent.

Answer (score 0):

I read a tutorial about gevent and fount a solution which is simple and clean for my needs:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO
import gevent
import os

def background_stuff():
    while True:
        try:
            print 'doing background work ... '
            gevent.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            return e

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_timers():
    return 'timer'

if __name__=='__main__':
    if os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') == 'true':
        gevent.spawn(background_stuff)
    socketio.run(app)
```

The tutorial can be found here: http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/#long-polling

It even tells about problems with gevent and multiprocesing: http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/#subprocess , but because I found a simple solution fitting to my needs I didn't try anything else.